# Sort UITableView by double

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a UITableView which sorts shops by their distance from the user. Although my distance calculator works, I don't know how to therefore sort the UITableView by this value, which is h. Here is my current code:

```
  @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var nearbyTableView: UITableView!
var myList: [String] = []





func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    var (cellName) = myList[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = cellName
    return cell

}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    var cellName = myList[indexPath.row]

     let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home2") as! ShopViewController
    viewController.name = cellName
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

    print("row\(indexPath.row)")
    print("name: \(cellName)")
}
```

The if statements calculate the distance of the shop. However, I have tried many different things, but I don't know how to therefore sort 'myList' with this value. It says that 'myList has no member h'. Any help is greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: Why you are sorting myList by .h? myList is defined as an array of strings; *var myList: [String] = []* and therefore .h makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to:

1. Sort the data array based on distance or whatever value you depend on.
2. Call tableview’s reloadData function to take effect.

I hope this helps

Comment: The issue is that I don't know how to sort the data array based on the value h

Comment: Which part of your code you want the sorting to be done?

Comment: It currently displays a list of the shops in no specific order, but each shop has a calculated distance (h). However, I need it to be in the order of the size of the distance.

Comment: There multiple things to be handled: You shall have an array of objects that you want to sort, and in object definition you must define Double h variable in order to sort your array.

Comment: The error you are seeing indicates that inside array mylist; object of type String does not have property by name “h” which you are using to sort. Also h variable is out of sorting scope

Comment: Well its not issues, more like basics. Anyway you have to create class or struct to contain “text” and “h” variables, then after you finish adding all objects and calculate distance then you sort objects based on h.